# How to update a Date field on all records when another record is inserted or updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This `update` runs as part of a stored proceducre that will `insert` or `update` a record in my `Information` table:

```
UPDATE [Information] SET
    [TermDate] = @aEffDate
WHERE [InformationID] = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(InformationID),0)
    FROM Information
    WHERE  InformationID <  @aInformationID
    AND [DeletedBy] IS NULL
    AND [DeletedOn] IS NULL
    AND Code = @aCode)
```

Basically, it looks for the second newest record (based off ID) and sets that record's `TermDate` to the current record's `EffDate`. The problem is that this assumes the user enters records in oldest-to-newest order.

I've added another clause to the nested `select` statement above to include `AND EffDate < @aEffDate`, which ensures the the date isn't improperly terminated. However, now I just have a bunch of records with `null` TermDate columns when the record that is returned from `MAX(InformationID)` has a greater `EffDate`

So, assume the following

1) Record entered with 11/02/2015 EffDate

2) Record entered with 09/01/2015 EffDate

3) Record entered with 10/03/2015 EffDate

4) Record entered with 09/15/2015 EffDate

The database WILL look this:

```
InformationID    |    EffDate   |    TermDate
---------------------------------------------
      1          |   11/02/15   |    09/01/15
      2          |   09/01/15   |    10/03/15
      3          |   10/03/15   |    09/15/15
      4          |   09/15/15   |      NULL
```

But it SHOULD look like this:

```
InformationID    |    EffDate   |    TermDate
---------------------------------------------
      1          |   11/02/15   |      NULL
      2          |   09/01/15   |    09/15/15
      3          |   10/03/15   |    11/02/15
      4          |   09/15/15   |    10/03/15
```

The user should have entered the records in the order of 2, 4, 3, 1 and this would assign the proper TermDate to each record. But unfortunately we can't really force them to do that.

**QUESTION** How can I get the get the EffDate closest to, but not less than, another record's EffDate and assign that value as the other record's TermDate?

I've removed the check for `InformationID` to simply make sure they're not the same; `InformationID <> @aInformationID` but beyond that I can't figure out how to get the "closest" dates.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions and an updatable CTE/subquery.  As a formal answer to your question, this should get the second to last record:

```
with toupdate as (
      select i.*,
             row_number() over (order by effdate desc) as seqnum
      from Information
      where DeletedBy IS NULL and DeletedOn IS NULL and Code = @aCode
     )
update toupdate
    set TermDate = @aEffDate
    where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the requirement of "closest to EffDate", does it? I re-editted my post with a more clear sample of current data and how it *should* be, instead. Basically if you insert 3 dates, the "oldest" record should have the "median" record's date, not simply the "newest" record's date.